# extracting mocked function for easier mocking of function behavior with jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, sequelize.js

I'm using jest with nodejs and sequelize for my models. For my testing, I wanted to mock the returned value of `findAll` to cover test scenarios. Sorry if this is a very newbie question but I'm at dead-end on this one.

**init-models.js**

```
module.exports = function initModels(sequelize) {
  //model relationship code here
  ...
  ...
  //end of model relationship code

  return {
    records,
    anotherModel,
    alsoAnotherModel
  };
};
```

**repository.js**

```
const sequelize = require('../sequelize');
const initModels = require('../model/init-models');

let {
  records,
  anotherModel,
  alsoAnotherModel
} = initModels(sequelize);

const fetchRecords = async () => {
  console.info('Fetching records...');
  return await records.findAll({sequelize parameters here});
}
```

**repository.test.js** This will work but needs the flexibility to mock `findAll()` return value/or throw Error

```
const repository = require('../../../src/db/repository/repository');
const initModels = require('../../../src/db/model/init-models');

jest.mock('../../../src/db/model/init-models', () => {
    return function() { 
        return {
            records: {
                findAll: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => [1,2,3])
            }
            //the rest of the code for other models
        }
    }
});

describe('fetchRecords', () => {
    beforeEach(()=> {
    });

    test('should return correct number of records', async () => {
        const result = await repository.fetchRecords();
        expect(result.size).toStrictEqual(3);        //test passed
    });
})
```

To allow mocking of results of `findAll`, I've tried extracting it so I can change the result per test scenario, but it was not working. What did I missed?

```
const mockRecordsFindAll = jest.fn();

jest.mock('../../../src/db/model/init-models', () => {
    return function() { 
        return {
            records: {
                findAll: () => mockRecordsFindAll
            }
            //the rest of the code for other models
        }
    }
});

describe('fetchRecords', () => {
    beforeEach(()=> {
        mockRecordsFindAll.mockReset()
    });

    test('should return correct number of records', async () => {
        mockRecordsFindAll.mockImplementation(() => [1,2,3]); //should expect length 3
        const result = await repository.fetchRecords();
        expect(result.size).toStrictEqual(3);            //fails, findAll was not mocked
    });
})
```

Comment: Try using `mockRecordsFindAll` as the value of `findAll`. `findAll: () => mockRecordsFindAll` -> `findAll: mockRecordsFindAll`.

Comment: I'll get the  `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockRecordsFindAll' before initialization`. I think this is because **jest** will hoist the `jest.mock(....)` to the top, before the initialization of `mockRecordsFindAll` when executed.

Comment: gotcha, You can use the `decorator pattern`. It should help with the hoist. `findAll: function () { return mockRecordsFindAll.call(this, arguments); }`

Comment: `findAll: function () { return mockRecordsFindAll.call(this, arguments); }` works! You can make your comment as an answer, will accept it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `mockRecordsFindAll` is being returned instead of executed.
As @Gid machined just returning `mockRecordsFindAll` causes initialization issues (due to hoisting).

The solution for this case is using the `decorator pattern` to allow `mockRecordsFindAll` to be initialized afterward.

```
const mockRecordsFindAll = jest.fn();

jest.mock('../../../src/db/model/init-models', () => {
    return function() { 
        return {
            records: {
                findAll: function () { 
                   return mockRecordsFindAll.call(this, arguments); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

describe('fetchRecords', () => {
    ...
})
```